# piping in real time

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts

This is more a conceptual thing than a current problem.

Would it be possible to do this:

`tail -f <file> | grep "string" | sed 's/stuff//g' >> output.txt`

The problem I'm thinking is that `tail -f` never terminates so it won't progress in the command. I'm trying to read and output a file in real-time. If this doesn't work how would I do it?

Comment: Yes, it works. I've personally done [something pretty similar with netcat](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162260/empty-a-file-without-grep-subsequently-treating-it-like-a-binary-file).

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work without problems. Even though tail never terminates, I believe it does not buffer it's output, so grep can consume it immediately. This may be specific to GNU tail

Comment: I tried it and it works, I didn't think I'd be able to test it today but my boss gave me access to the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most commands that output data on stdout, (which includes `grep` and `sed`,) buffer their output when it's not going to a terminal. That is, they wait for a large chunk of output to gather (like 4KiB) before *flushing* the chunk to the file or pipe. This is generally more efficient. Some commands allow you to override this, like GNU `grep` which has a `--line-buffered` option, and GNU `sed` has an `--unbuffered` option. For commands that don't have a way to override the buffering, you can use tools like `unbuffer` or `stdbuf`.

In this case though, I'd consider using GNU `awk` instead, where you can control the flushing of stdout yourself (with the fflush function).

```
tail -f file | gawk '/string/{ gsub(/stuff/, "") } { print; fflush() }' > output.txt
```

See [BashFAQ #9](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) for more on buffering.

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much. Wasn't sure if I had to use the `buffer` option on every command.